# Can I change the user that is the default choice in UAC?

Tags: windows-7, user-accounts, uac

Windows 7 install.

I RANU, so I have to hit the UAC every once in awhile.  The problem is that it asks me to enter my password to elevate, but I need to enter the domain\username of the box admin (I'm on a domain) and the password.

Instead of UAC popping up with my username entered and the caret in the password box, I'd like it to pop up with the domain\username of a different user, specifically the local admin account, entered.  This would save me a click and some typing.  Sue me, I'm lazy.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as i know there's no option to select the default user in UAC dialog. The only choice is to disable UAC completly (which not a good idea IMHO).

Microsoft forgot to add the option "use the selected user for default" in the dialog box.